# Open Url in new tab without browser Pop Up

Tags: javascript, url, browser, window.open

Code should open URL into new tab with no user interaction. Already tried:

```
var dummyClick = document.createElement('a');
dummyClick.href = newUrl;
dummyClick.target = '_blank';
dummyClick.click();

window.open(newUrl,'_blank');

window.open(newUrl,'newwin');
```

Also tried with `location.href`.

Can this be done with javascript?

Comment: Tried it in my end, it is opening a new tab without browser pop up. what is the problem you are facing?

Comment: Whether it opens in a new tab or a new window is browser behaviour as far as I am aware. I don't think that can be controlled through javascript. Some browsers will open in a new tab, and some in a new window.

Comment: Pop Up Blockers, saving us from annoying ads since early 2000.

Comment: @ClementAmarnath You might have the popups enabled on the site, As  I have disabled popus from browser settings and user may have it also then how we will trigger it

Answer (score 0):

> Code will open URL into new tab no user interaction will be there

This is precisely the behaviour that popup blockers were designed to prevent. [HTML 5 standardises the rules](https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/single-page.html#allowed-to-show-a-popup).

You can't trigger a new tab or window in response to the user arriving on a page. You can only do it in response to an interactive event.

Comment: Expanding on that, most browsers allow these programmatic approaches to occur successfully as long as it happens synchronously within the callback of a mouse event.

Comment: @PatrickRoberts — That would be an example of an interactive event. A keypress would be another.